# show divs with unique id each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a photo library with comments but I'm stuck in the comment button of every image.

The html structure is something like:

```
<form>
    <div>
        // some buttons - options
        <a id="show_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="">Comment</a>
    </div>
    // the div hidding the comments section
    <div id="hide_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class=""></div>
</form>
```

Everyting ok with one single div, but the problem is that is inside a foreach printing images so I'm not sure how to tell (or where) jscript to read that img_id. I'm using jquery to toggle the div:

in the code before the form (still in the foreach):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img_id = ' . json_encode($img_id) . ';
</script>
```

and the javascript/jquery:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#show_'+img_id).on('click', function() {
        $('#hide_'+img_id).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

That's working fine, the problem is that only the last id is working (only the last image's button show the comments section).

I'm pretty sure the problem is the javascript variable, because only the last one is working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **html5 data attribute** and use **class** selector in the following way:

```
<a id="show_' . $row['img_id'] . '" data-id="' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="show">
```

and in jquery:

```
$(function() {  
    $('.show').on('click', function() {
        $('#hide_'+$(this).data("id")).slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

`$(this).data("id")` will give the current click elemtent **data-id** attribute value and concatenated it in the **#hide_** selector to hide the relevant element.

Comment: gald to help @ChazyChaz

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your links, and also a `data-id` attribute with the value of image id.
And when you click on the button, the get the clicked buttons data-id value, and now you can know what image you want to show.

```
<form>
    <div>
        // some buttons - options
        <a id="show_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="mybutton" data-id="'.$row['img_id'].'">Comment</a>
    </div>
    // the div hidding the comments section
    <div id="hide_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class=""></div>
</form>
```

And then

```
$('.mybutton'.on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#hide_'+id).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer (and the fastest of the two similar). I second this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class as trigger instead. This way you can have an infinite amount of elements with the same class and add the id in an custom html attribute.

For example you got multiple buttons:

```
<a class="image_action" image_id="1">Just</a>
<a class="image_action" image_id="2">Some</a>
<a class="image_action" image_id="3">Text</a>
```

Then create a global onClick-trigger for every element with class "image_action" and use $(this) to get actual id:

```
$(".image_action").on("click", function() {
    var targetID = $(this).attr("image_id");
    if(targetID > 0) {
        $('#image_' + targetID).slideToggle('fast');
    }
});
```

My sample is not identical to your code but I think you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

That's because after the page is loaded `img_id` will be overwritten by the next value in the `foreach` thus giving only the last value.

Why not using `class` instead and transverse to its corresponding comment's `div` like so:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div>
        // some buttons - options
        <a id="show_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="showIt">Comment</a>
    </div>
    // the div hidding the comments section
    <div id="hide_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="comment"></div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {  
    $('.showIt').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.comment').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: So no need to use ids? Will work every button for the corresponding div? If I add more classes (class="showIt style1 style2") will work?

Comment: Yes, no need of ids. Yes it will.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the markup, then use `$(this)`.

For example;

PHP

```
<a id="show_' . $row['img_id'] . '" class="CommentLink">Comment</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(".CommentLink").click( function() {
   var imageId = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
   var imageId = imageId[1];
   $('#hide_' + imageId).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

#### Example;

```js
    $(".CommentLink").click( function() {
       var imageId = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
       var imageId = imageId[1];
       $('#hide_' + imageId).show();
    });
```

```css
.com {
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="show_1" class="CommentLink">Comment 1</a>
<a id="show_2" class="CommentLink">Comment 2</a>

<div id="hide_1" class="com">Comments for image 1</div>
<div id="hide_2" class="com">Comments for image 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm checking.